# In Rails, how do I create a migration that will change the type of my primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, primary-key, uuid

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with PostGres.  I have created several tables, all of which have numeric primary keys.  Below is an example of one of my Rails migrations

```
class CreateMyObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_objects do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.date :day
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I do not have any data in this table, but I do have several tables that link to it through foreign keys.  I want to change the primary key from being a numeric primary key to a GUID (UUID) because I’m going to have a situation where data gets created in two different databases and I don’t want there to be primary key collisions when I combine the data.  How do I create a migration that will change the primary key’s type from being numeric to my UUID type and how do I update all the foreign keys that link to the table?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: that's one case I'd advocate dropping the foreign key in time for the update, tbh..

Comment: I'm not understanding your comment.  Please give an example.

Comment: temporary remove the foreign key so that you can violate the integrity (in a transaction)

Comment: How would I even perform the migration in the first place?

Comment: You haven't explained well. How can we reproduce it on our local?

Comment: Think about it like this -- I have a table with a numeric primary key and I want to make the primary key type a UUID.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

```
class ChangePrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :my_objects, :id # remove existing primary key
    add_column    :my_objects, :uuid, :string
    execute "ALTER TABLE my_objects ADD PRIMARY KEY (uuid);"
  end
end

class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :uuid
end
```

As to auto incrementing - no, Rails won't increment your string `id` for you, so you'll have to take care of it on your own.

You can use a `before_create` callback in the model:

```
before_create :generate_uuid

  private

  def generate_uuid
    loop do
      self.uuid = SecureRandom.base64(16)         # or other way to generate uniq string
      break unless self.class.find_by(uuid: uuid) # make sure you don't repeat the uuid
    end
  end
```

You can also add constraints to the primary_key column, like `not null` constraint, `uniqueness`, `length` etc

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't address the tables taht have foreign keys to this table.  Indeed, when I run this migration, I get the error, “PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table my_objects column id because other objects depend on it, DETAIL:  constraint fk_rails_27b0854e5e on table user_my_objects depends on table races column id”

Comment: @Dave it's a specific case. You have to create a migration, that will remove foreign_key from associated tables' objects, than execute the one from my answer, and than add the associations through new foreign key (in new migration).

Comment: How do I create such a migration?  Also, you named the primary key column uuid.  Can I just keep it as named "id" to keep with conventions?

Comment: @Dave sure, you can name it as you wish. Please, provide me with table, that is associated with the `my_objects` table and define the association - I'll try to write the migration

Comment: Its cool, I foudn some code taht performs the mgiration.  ONe last question, when the ID field was an integer, it was auto-populated?  Will this still happen?  That was certainly one of the nice things from before -- not having to manage the values of the IDs.

Comment: @Dave unfortunately you'll have to manage it on your own, but, happily, it's quit easy, see the updated answer